# How to search data from enum file

Tags: laravel, enums, enumeration

I have a enum file name 'EmployeePosition' which contain 'position list' and i want to search here a position name. Is any way to search here name?

```
enum EmployeePosition:int {
    case Manager = 1;
    case Officer = 2;
    case Executive = 3;
    case Worker = 4;

    public static function name(string $name){
        return constant("self::$name");
    }
}
```

Comment: if u r trying to add roles in ur laravel app i recommend u following this way - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: no this not role and it is not possible to me using database table. i have to work with enum file.

Comment: It's not quiet clear to me what you want to do. You want to list all the available enum options? Or you want to look for an option and verify it exists?

Comment: I just want to search a name from enum file. If the name is exists then return me true or if not exists return false.